# Boolean operators which return one of the operands

Tags: javascript, operators, boolean

In Python, and maybe in Javascript, the boolean `or` and `and` operators return one of the operands, instead of `true` or `false`.

- In Python, one of the operands is returned: `'' || 'hello' == 'hello'`
- In comparison, in PHP: `'' || 'hello' == true`;

Now,

- How is this behavior of boolean operators called?
- Does this also work in Javascript in all browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Ignacio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227102/boolean-operators-which-return-one-of-the-operands/3227111#3227111) points out, these are **coalescing** operators.  `||` is the [null coalescing operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator), `&&` is the null-safe coalescing operator (<strike>link to follow, if I can find one</strike> sorry, I can't find a link).

They should be available in all browsers - they are both defined in the ECMA-262 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 5th editions, most current Javascript implementations are based upon 3rd or 5th.  From ECMA-262 3rd edition:

> The production LogicalANDExpression : LogicalANDExpression && BitwiseORExpression is evaluated as
>   follows:
>   1. Evaluate LogicalANDExpression.
>   2. Call GetValue(Result(1)).
>   3. Call ToBoolean(Result(2)).
>   4. If Result(3) is false, return Result(2).
>   5. Evaluate BitwiseORExpression.
>   6. Call GetValue(Result(5)).
>   7. Return Result(6).
>
> The production LogicalORExpression : LogicalORExpression || LogicalANDExpression is evaluated as
>   follows:
>   1. Evaluate LogicalORExpression.
>   2. Call GetValue(Result(1)).
>   3. Call ToBoolean(Result(2)).
>   4. If Result(3) is true, return Result(2).
>   5. Evaluate LogicalANDExpression.
>   6. Call GetValue(Result(5)).
>   7. Return Result(6).

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that while `||` is the closest that JavaScript has to a null coalescing operator (not including proposals), it may more aptly be referred to as a *falsy* coalescing operator. (I realize I'm commenting on this 9 years later, but it was referenced as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58034151/why-true-string-equals-string-and-not-true-in-js) today.)

Answer (score 1):

It's called "coalescing". It should behave the same in any browser that claims to be compliant.

Answer (score 0):

A [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56463632/why-do-boolean-operators-in-javascript-not-return-boolean-values) has been re-directed here, and although I agree that the central question has been answered accurately at a high level, part of the newer question seems to be asking about the difference between logical OR and the ternary operator in Javascript.

I would like to offer a low-level example to demonstrate the difference because I wrote most of this before the question was redirected, and the concept of a `null-coalescing operator` is rather abstract.

Consider these functions, which can be run in the browser console or any repl:

```
let logicalOrTest = function(val) { 
  let a = 2;
  let b = 3;
  console.log(val === a);
  console.log(val === b);
  console.log(val === (a || b));
  console.log(val !== (a || b));
}
```

Expect `logicalOrTest(2)` to log `true false true false`

Expect `logicalOrTest(3)` to log `false true false true`

Expect `logicalOrTest(4)` to log `false false false true`

This reveals that comparing any value `val` to `(a || b)` will return `true` when the value is equivalent to the first condition, and `false` for any other value, *including* the second.

To put it simply, if condition `a` is met, condition `b` is not even considered. On the other hand, if condition `a` is not met, `b` *will be considered* before determining what to do.

Now let's look at the ternary operator:

```
let ternaryTest = function(val) { 
  let a = 2;
  let b = 3;
  val === a ? console.log(true) : console.log(false);
  val === b ? console.log(true) : console.log(false);
  val === (a || b) ? console.log(true) : console.log(false);
  val !== (a || b) ? console.log('neither condition was met') : console.log('wat');
}
```

Expect `ternaryTest(2)` to log `true false true "wat"`

Expect `ternaryTest(3)` to log `false true false "neither condition was met"`

Expect `ternaryTest(4)` to log `false false false "neither condition was met"`

Like logical OR (`||`), the ternary operator `x ? x : y` will pass any *falsy* value into the scope of the second expression, which also includes values equivalent to the second condition. If condition `a` is met, condition `b` is not considered.

*The difference is* that if condition `a` is *not* met in a ternary operation, expression `a` will be ignored and expression `b` will *always* be executed.

So, while they can be used for similar purposes, it's important to understand which one is more efficient--especially if you are triggering large blocks of code within the scope of your operation.