# Why (true && 'string') equals 'string' and not true in JS?

Tags: javascript

If `("") results false,` so why isn't `(true && "") false` instead of `""` (`empty string)`.

And `if("string") results true`, so why isn't `(true && "string") true` instead of `'string'`.

Same goes for objects,

For example `(true && {key: 'val'})` is not true, it's `{key: 'val'}`

Comment: `""` is *falsy*, thus `(true && "")` evaluating to a *falsy* is perfectly in line with the expected result.

Answer (score -2):

Because it's the same as if (true) return "string"  `if (condition) return result`.

Never matter what the result **(** **String**, **Object**, **Boolean** **...)** it will be returned if the condition is **true**.

also you can use that as a short hand for `if (condition) return res` could be

```
condition && res
```

[Logical AND (&&)   expr1 && expr2  If expr1 can be converted to true, returns expr2; else, returns expr1.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

```js
(() => {

  console.log(true && "string")

  if (true) {
    return "string"
  }

})()
```